# Join three table for Report in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to produce report for airlines using

1. Date Table
2. Airline Table
3. Route Table

My date table include series of date

```
    Entryid | Date 
    ----------------
       1    |2016-06-01
       2    |2016-06-02
       4    |2016-06-03
       5    |2016-06-04
       6    |2016-06-05
       7    |2016-06-06
```

My airline table include

```
id|name
---------
1 |Air1
2 |Air2
3 |Air3
```

and Route table:

```
id|date     |airline|routename
1|2016-06-01|1      |city1-city2
2|2016-06-01|1      |city1-city3
3|2016-06-01|2      |city1-city3
4|2016-06-02|2      |city1-city3
5|2016-06-02|2      |city1-city3
6|2016-06-04|2      |city1-city3
7|2016-06-04|2      |city1-city3
8|2016-06-04|1      |city1-city3
```

by using these three table I want to produce result as follow"

```
    Date   |Airline|totleroute
2016-06-01 |  Air1 | 2
2016-06-01 |  Air2 | 1
2016-06-02 |  Air1 | 0
2016-06-02 |  Air2 | 2
2016-06-03 |  Air1 | 0
2016-06-03 |  Air2 | 0
2016-06-04 |  Air1 | 1
2016-06-04 |  Air2 | 2
```

How to produce desired result from joining three tables?

Comment: For 2015-06-03 you have no entry in Route table, but there are entries in your result for 'Air1' and 'Air2'. This would would be ok, if there would exist entries for 'Air3' on each day. Do you want '0' entries for each day and airline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a query like the following:

```sql
SELECT d.`date`, t.`name`, COUNT(r.`routename`) AS TotalRoutes
FROM `Date` AS d
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT r.`airline`, a.`name`
  FROM Route AS r 
  INNER JOIN Airline AS a ON r.airline = a.id
) AS t   
LEFT JOIN Route AS r ON d.`date` = r.`date` AND t.`airline` = r.`airline`
GROUP BY d.`date`, t.`airline`
```

The `CROSS JOIN` is used in order to produce a result for each `date` - `airline` combination, as suggested by the sample output in the OP.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/71f00a/12)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this query:

```
select e.date,a.name airline, count(r.id) total_route from route_tbl r
LEFT join entry_tbl e on r.date =e.date
LEFT join airline_tbl a on a.id= r.id
order by r.date
group by r.date
```

Comment: The `LEFT JOIN` would not produce rows for dates where no route is scheduled (`totalroutes = 0`).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need a so called `FULL JOIN` to have all combinations of Date and Route entries with a column containing the number of routes per day and airline.

Regrettably MySQL lacks support for `FULL JOIN`, there is a [feature request open since some years](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18003&thanks=3&notify=67).

It is still possible to emulate such a feature. A good reading would be https://explainextended.com/2009/04/06/emulating-full-outer-join-in-mysql/